# How to Refresh ADF jsf page components by pressing a button?

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I have a fusion web application that contains an af:query panel (I created it query panel with table), and af:table and af:panelFormLayout that are related with each other. When I search an entry in the query panel results are shown  both in table and in panelFormLayout. When I press reset button in the query panel, only the query panel is reset. I want to all the page to reset. How can I do that by using the easiness of ADF?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to override the reset functionality of the af:query. In that case, you should:
1. Set the QueryListener property of the af:query to a managed bean method. You can refer to this example which describes all the steps required: [Programmatically RESET query panel](http://andrejusb.blogspot.com/2009/09/programmatical-reset-for-query-results.html)
Inside it, you'll see this call: `AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(t1);`
It is responsible for the refresh of the table. Now, if you have all the content inside an af:panelGroupLayout for example (or any other payout type component), you can refresh it instead (so you need to bind it with a field on the bean and use it instead of **t1** in this call. Otherwise, if you still wish the full page refresh, follow step 2.

2. Add the needed code to make the page refresh:

```
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String currentView = context.getViewRoot().getViewId();
    ViewHandler vh = context.getApplication().getViewHandler();
    UIViewRoot x = vh.createView(context, currentView);
    x.setViewId(currentView);
    context.setViewRoot(x);
```

Just put it inside the method described on the above link.

[image]

Comment: How can I access the backing bean source of the jsf page in 11g?

Comment: Well that hasn't changed, throught an EL like this:<br>
  <af:query id="qryId2"  disclosed="true"                                          value="#{bindings.VO.queryDescriptor}"                                          model="#{bindings.ContractSearchCriteriaQuery.queryModel}"                                          queryListener="#{bindings.VO.processQuery}"                                          queryOperationListener="#{beanName.methodName}"                    resultComponentId="::pc1:t1"

Comment: I mean, where can I find the java source code of my jsf page then I can add my own codes and change methods?

Comment: I am amazed to read such a question. How are you working with ADF and don't even know such a thing? I am editing my answer to post an image illustrating what i think you are looking for.

Comment: Because I was not looking for the information in that image, of course I already know it. Your answer helps me without the image, thank you