# How to hide AFD component in JDeveloper when button clicked?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have tried the following to hide an ADF component but it doesn't work, any idea what im doing wrong?

#{Not mainBean.RequestBean.applyButton.selected}

What I expected this line to do is hide a table when the applyButton is clicked but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Refresh ADF jsf page components by pressing a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25054326/how-to-refresh-adf-jsf-page-components-by-pressing-a-button)

Answer (score 1):

You need to refresh the component when the button is clicked for the condition to be true. At the end of the button event add :

```java
UIComponent component = findComponentInRoot("YOUR_COMPONEND_ID");
AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(component.getParent()); //This will ask adf to trigger an ajax refresh on your component
```

To find the component in your java bean :

```java
    /**
 * Locate an UIComponent in view root with its component id. Use a recursive way to achieve this.
 * @param id UIComponent id
 * @return UIComponent object
 */
public static UIComponent findComponentInRoot(String id) {
    UIComponent component = null;
    if (id != null) {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        if (facesContext != null) {
            UIComponent root = facesContext.getViewRoot();
            if (root != null) {
                component = findComponent(root, id);
            }
        }
    }
    return component;
}
```